# Entity Framework insert row into relational table

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have defined 2 classes:

```
public class Student 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Student_FName { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProgramName { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

This created the tables accurately, with `StudentId` as FK in `Program` table.

Now I am trying to insert data using below Json and getting error. How to solve it? I just wish to enter `Maths` as program for `Student` with Id = 1

```
{
    "programName": "Math",
    "studentId": 1
}
{
```

I get this error:

```
"errors": {
    "Student": [
        "The Student field is required."
    ]
},
"title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status": 400,
"traceId": "00-7d3f8f9048ccf69b10f647fc7781f4a7-fa99172258bd6e1a-00"
```

Why do I have to enter the `Student` object again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark `Student` property as `virtual` in your code to let EF know that it's a navigation property and the deserializer - that it's not required.

```
public class Program
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProgramName { get; set; }
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: The virtual modifier does *not* mark a property as navigation property. It only has bearing on lazy loading, which is not required. The code as shown should normally work. Something else is going on.